# OSError exception '[Errno 2] No such file or directory' when using subprocess.check_output()

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, exiftool

I am trying to read meta information from a jpg file using subprocess to execute an ExifTool read command.

The function that calls get_dimensions() first creates the file, stores its file path in file_name--I double-checked and it does indeed exist where it should--and eventually calls get_dimensions(). Calling subprocess.check_output() in this function always raises an OSError. I'm running pytest on python 2.7.10 by the way.

```
def get_dimensions(self, file_name):
    exiftool = subprocess.check_output(['exiftool', '-j', file_name])
    exif = json.loads(exiftool)[0]
    width, height = (exif.get('ImageWidth', 0), exif.get('ImageHeight', 0))
    return (width, height)
```

The error is:

```
Exception has occurred: OSError 
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
  File "/Users/derek/m-app-tests/tests/TestUtils/client_api.py", line 428, in get_dimensions
    exiftool = subprocess.check_output(['exiftool', '-j', file_name])
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I didn't have exiftool installed.